# Facebook boost page post using API

Tags: facebook

I looked around in the Facebook API documentation but couldn't find any information on boosting a page post. So I was wondering is it possible to boost a page's post from the API?

Comment: Apparently it's possible according to this Quora answer - http://www.quora.com/Why-doesnt-Facebook-allow-you-to-boost-a-page-post-through-the-API , but no instructions or link are provided.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the Facebook Marketing API documentation. There are details about Page Promotion here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/unpublished-page-posts/v2.4#promote